# Software installation on Linux HPC Cluster setup

Tags: linux, mpi, cluster-computing, hpc

I am trying to set up a Linux HPC Cluster with a head node (login/compilation/dev), NAS (File system) and few compute nodes. All the machines will have the home directory mounted from NAS. My question is how should I go about installing the common software and libraries, such as gcc, mpi, etc.? Should I install it once on the shared directory or install it separately on all the compute nodes' local HDD.

Installing it once seems a better option and easier to manage but would it affect performance? Or once the executable is loaded on to memory and starts running it won't matter?

If I install it separately on all machines' local HDD then updating in the future would be difficult and also the chances of running out of storage potential.

Thanks in advance.